# Random image with javascript doesnt want to give the src

Tags: javascript, image, random

I want to show a random picture with every refresh but I don't know why my code is not working... probably because I'm bad at javascript, haha.

I tried "3" instead of "imgs.length", but it's still not working - I too don't really want to give an exact number, because the image count may vary.. only for my example I use three images.

```
var imgs = ['img1','img2','img3'];

function getRandomImage(){
 var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length);
 document.getElementById('pr_randImage').src = imgs[rnd];
}   
</script>   

<img id="pr_randImage">
```

Quellcode is just not showing any src at all for the img. What am I doing wrong? I'm thankful for every help.

Comment: When do you call your function? And do the images in your array have a full filename with path and extension, or is it exactly as you have above?

Comment: Call your function after document load

Comment: Use the setAttribute function

Comment: With path and extensions, yes, I just put it like this for this example. I'm totally new to this, so sorry for my question: do you mean by "call your function" something like "onload="getRandomImage()""? Do I need this for the code to work? Because I do not have it in there yet but it's actually a template of a forum I'm working on, so there's no "body" to get the onload with... and on a div it does not seem to work?

Comment: .setAttribute('src',imgs[rnd])  <--- like this? because still not working :/

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var imgs = ['img1','img2','img3'];
```

to something like this depending on extension of the image you are using

```
var imgs = ['img1.png','img2.png','img3.jpg'];
```

If that still doesn't work then you need to include the path of where the images are

Something like this

```
document.getElementById('pr_randImage').src = "/images/" + imgs[rnd];
```

Comment: those are just examples, i put the whole urls there, but still not working :/

Comment: Put <img id="pr_randImage"> before <script> if that works you need to use onload to make sure the DOM is ready before Javascript execute. It worth checking the error console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Putting it before the script did not change anything sadly